# Pandas Multi-Index rendering

Tags: python, pandas

I often need to produce tables of descriptive statistics by groups of individuals and on several variables. I almost reach the desired result as is reproduced below (columns = groups of individuals, rows = stats by variable of interest):

```
group_name        ELF-TA    TOTAL  TOTAL not TA  TOTAL-TA
           stat                                          
nb_c_3km   25%      2.00     1.00          1.00      2.00
           50%      4.00     3.00          2.00      4.00
           75%      6.00     5.00          4.00      6.00
           count  250.00 1,816.00      1,442.00    374.00
           max     17.00    21.00         21.00     16.00
           mean     4.58     3.37          3.14      4.23
           min      0.00     0.00          0.00      0.00
           std      3.14     3.12          3.13      2.93
dist_c     25%      0.45     0.53          0.54      0.50
           50%      0.89     1.01          1.04      0.94
           75%      1.48     1.95          2.15      1.46
           count  250.00 1,836.00      1,462.00    374.00
           max      6.80    19.68         19.68      7.75
           mean     1.17     1.78          1.92      1.21
           min      0.00     0.00          0.00      0.00
           std      1.13     2.25          2.43      1.16
```

From this I'd like to be able to extract the stats I want and in the order I want e.g. simply display mean, std and median. I get close to this with the following line:

```
df_groups_desc.loc[(slice(None), ['mean', 'std', '50%']),:]
```

... but close only because I don't get the stats displayed in the desired order:

```
group_name       ELF-TA  TOTAL  TOTAL not TA  TOTAL-TA
           stat                                       
nb_c_3km   50%     4.00   3.00          2.00      4.00
           mean    4.58   3.37          3.14      4.23
           std     3.14   3.12          3.13      2.93
dist_c     50%     0.89   1.01          1.04      0.94
           mean    1.17   1.78          1.92      1.21
           std     1.13   2.25          2.43      1.16
```

Any hint about a reasonable solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`reindex` can select rows in order:

```
new_index, indexer = df.index.reindex(['mean', 'std', '50%'], level=1)
df = df.reindex(index=new_index)
print(df)
```

yields

```
               ELF-TA TOTAL TOTAL not TA  TOTAL-TA
dist_c   mean    1.17  1.78         1.92      1.21
         std     1.13  2.25         2.43      1.16
         50%     0.89  1.01         1.04      0.94
nb_c_3km mean    4.58  3.37         3.14      4.23
         std     3.14  3.12         3.13      2.93
         50%     4.00  3.00         2.00      4.00
```

Comment: For the record: it didn't work with pandas 0.15.0 for some reason, but it's fine with 0.15.2. Thanks a lot!